# Circuit that accept 4-bit number and generate its triple, what does that mean? Can someone give me an example of it?

Tags: boolean, bit, boolean-logic, circuit

I have to design a combinational circuit that accepts a 4-bit number and generate its triple, what does it mean? Can someone please give me an example of a specific input and its output so I can understand the question?

If you could give me also any hint for designing this circuit I would be very grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: It means the output should be 3 times the input

Comment: Input: a 4-bit number, between 0 and 15. Output: a 6-bit number, between 0 and 45.

Comment: If you're not concerned about using the minimum possible logic, and you like reusing things, just chain a couple of adders together. Add your input to itself, then add the result to the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with a truth table:

```
IN              OUT
 0   0 0 0 0     0   0 0 0 0 0 0
 1   0 0 0 1     3   0 0 0 0 1 1
 2   0 0 1 0     6   0 0 0 1 1 0
 3   0 0 1 1     9   0 0 1 0 0 1
 4   0 1 0 0     C   0 0 1 1 0 0
 5   0 1 0 1     F   0 0 1 1 1 1
 6   0 1 1 0    12   0 1 0 0 1 0
 7   0 1 1 1    15   0 1 0 1 0 1
 8   1 0 0 0    18   0 1 1 0 0 0
 9   1 0 0 1    1B   0 1 1 0 1 1
 A   1 0 1 0    1E   0 1 1 1 1 0
 B   1 0 1 1    21   1 0 0 0 0 1
 C   1 1 0 0    24   1 0 0 1 0 0
 D   1 1 0 1    27   1 0 0 1 1 1
 E   1 1 1 0    2A   1 0 1 0 1 0
 F   1 1 1 1    2D   1 0 1 1 0 1
```

Then use a standard technique such as a [Karnaugh Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) to deduce the input/output expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to make a truth table and then derive the combinational logic from either boolean algebra (sum of truths), or from a k-map.

If, for example, the input is `0100` which is decimal 4, then the triple would be 12, or `1100`. Since the highest number is `1111` (15), then your output has to be able to represent 45, or `101101` (6 bits).

Hence, you'll have something like:

```
Input | Output
-----------------
abcd     uvwxyz
0000  | 000000
0001  | 000011
0010  | 000110
0011  | 001001
0100  | 001100
0101  | 001111
0110  | 010010
0111  | 010101
1000  | 011000
1001  | 011011
1010  | 011110
1011  | 100001
1100  | 100100
1101  | 100111
1110  | 101010
1111  | 101101
```

From that you can build a k-map for each output bit and find the minimum combinational logic required per output bit.

For example, to find the combinational logic for bit `u` then you would use the following k-map:

```
         AB
      00 01 11 10
CD 00 0  0  1  0
   01 0  0  1  0
   11 0  0  1  1
   10 0  0  1  0
```

Which reduces to `ACD + AB`

Repeat for the other 5 bits (v-z) and you'll have the full combinational logic needed to implement the solution.

Comment: The k map for u is wrong, for ABCD=1110 u=1 and not 0. So we should have 5 1s instead of 4. Right?